# Setting the layout in Controller

Tags: c#, layout, asp.net-core-mvc

In Previous versions of MVC I was able to set the layout in the controller using the [`View()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.String%29).

```
public class MyController
{
  public ActionResult Test1()
  {
    return View("Test", "Layout1");
  }
  public ActionResult Test2()
  {
    return View("Test", "Layout2");
  }
}
```

However it appears that in the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Mvc/Controller/index.html#methods) there is no overload for View that takes the Layout/Template/Masterpage as a parameter.

Adding logic to all my models or views is really a terrible option for this logic, so is there an alternative in the controller method?

Asp.Net MVC 6/Core [Controller Source Code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs).

Comment: Weird, Works fine for me.

Comment: You're using [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] aka MVC 6?

Comment: As of asp.net core 2.2 there still appears to be no View method overload

Answer (score 1):

It feels dirty, but I did:

No magic strings (Theory):

```
public enum ViewDataType
{
    Layout = 0
}
```

ViewData Extensions

```
public static class ViewDataExtensions
{
    public static void Add(this ViewDataDictionary viewData, ViewDataType viewDataType, object value)
    {
        viewData.Add(viewDataType.ToString(), value);
    }

    public static TResult Get<TResult>(this ViewDataDictionary viewData, ViewDataType viewDataType)
        where TResult : class
    {
        var result = viewData[viewData.ToString()] as TResult;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Controller Extensions:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static IActionResult View(this Controller instance, object model, string layout)
    {
        instance.ViewData.Add(ViewDataType.Layout, layout);
        return instance.View(model);
    }

    public static IActionResult View(this Controller instance, string viewName, object model, string layout)
    {
        instance.ViewData.Add(ViewDataType.Layout, layout);
        return instance.View(viewName, model);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
  // blah blah logic

  var result = this.View("ViewName", model, "Layouts/Default");
}
```

and in the ViewStart:

```
var layout = this.ViewData.Get<string>(ViewDataType.Layout)
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(layout))
{
    Layout = "Layouts/Default";
}
else
{
    Layout = layout;
}
```